# Subversion / Cornerstone - How to upgrade working copy

Tags: svn, upgrade, working-copy, cornerstone

I have been using Cornerstone client on a mac to update a project without issue until yesterday when without warning I began receiving the following error message:

```
"Working copy '/Users/Si/Documents/workspace/CCA_NewAPI/src/com' is too old (format 10,     created by Subversion 1.6)"
```

I am unable to commit or do anything else with the working copy now. I update Cornerstone to the latest version but that didn't help at all.

Some research told me to use the terminal to navigate to the working copy directory and run 'svn upgrade' but I receive the following result:

```
Unknown command: 'upgrade'
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

Any assistance on how to upgrade the working copy will be gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: Check `svn --version`, you CLI-client is still 1.6. `upgrade` is command of 1.7

Answer (score 5):

You can upgrade the wording copy in Cornerstone. Select your working copy on the left and then go to the Working Copy menu at the top. Choose "Upgrade Working Copy" and then choose the version to upgrade to. In your case, it looks like you should upgrade to 1.7.

Source: [Cornerstone Help](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/helpbook/pages/getting-started/add-working-copy.html)

Comment: And if that option is greyed out?